# How to integrate video to image target in Unity 2022 version?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Unity version 2022.3.16f
With the Vuforia package, I need to integrate a video on a real image within the scope of Augmented Reality. For this, I create a plane on the image target in Hierarchy and assign a video to the inspector window. However, when I test, the video does not move on the plane, only a white image appears.
Briefly, how can I integrate video on image target. can you explain in detail?

1. Tried older versions (unity 2020,2021)
2. I tried playing video by assigning render texture or quad instead of plane.
3. I tried to do it using different videos. I am also sure that it is MP4 extension.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your video might not be playing because there is no trigger to start it. If you see the [Vuforia's Core Samples](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/packs/vuforia-core-samples-99026), there's an Image Target with a video playing when the image is detected. I would grab that GameObject with its children and replace the video in the Video Player component's *Video Clip* field. Their sample even has a play and pause controller script that you can use.
[image: Image Target Core Samples from Vuforia showing the Unity setup of a playing a video when an Image Target is detected]

Otherwise, I would:

1. Make a plane GameObject as a child of the Image Target,
2. Disable its Mesh Renderer,
3. Add the Video Player component,
4. Add the path to my video in the *Video Clip* field,
5. Disable the *Play On Awake*,
6. Add an item to the OnTargetFound() in the DefaultObserverEventHandler component and drag the Plane GameObject into the Object field.
7. Then select VideoPlayer.Play() in the Function dropdown menu.
   [image: Simple Image Target setup for playing a video when the target is found]